# source classes for android views

Tags: java, android

It is kind of a general question but I noticed that I needed it multiple times and could not find an answer.

There are many cases where I needed to change a view to make it work for my specific purposes and I needed to create a custom `TextView`, custom `EditText`, custom `autoCompleteTextView` and so on.

Where can I find those source codes so I could use them and change them for my purposes?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new class extend from TextView or EditText and do it.
To find source codes you can with ctrl+U on class.

Comment: The ctrl+U is good to know =]. But for example, im standing on autoCompleteTextView and using ctrl+U but it wont open the source class of it.

Comment: Try "Navigate -> Declaration or Usage" on AutoCompleteTextView

Comment: Thanks for the help, it did the job